# iOS user defined files Not found

Tags: ios

On my iOS Project Build Setting

I have defined user search path of the library asio.

```
   Always Search USer Paths: Yes
   USer Header Search Paths:"/asio-1.4.8/compiled/include"
```

So on my file, I have

```
   #include "asio.hpp"
```

The error is file asio.hpp not found. 
But I checked inside and the file is there of the folder /asio-1.4.8/compiled/include

Comment: Make sure the asio.hpp is included in the target you are building. Have you actually added this file/folder to your Xcode project?

Comment: inside /asio-1.4.8/compiled/include  there is asio.hpp but also contains a folder asio which contains many more .hpp files. Do I need to add all these files too?      Can I simply just add the folder /asio-1.4.8/compiled/include into the project?      This is bit odd. In the normal C/C++ project when I have the include path, the project would find those files and but you don't need add those files into the project explicitly or manually

Comment: Is the path really `/asio-1.4.8`? Or is this a path relative to your project?